# Does tensorflow compute the cross entropy only with single precision?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cross-entropy

I am trying to fully understand the computation of the cross entropy in TensorFlow. In the following piece of code, with numpy I generate double precision random double data `x`, transform it to `logits` for binary classification (i.e., only one logit per data point), map it through sigmoid in `sig`, compute the cross entropy `ce` and then the mean cross entropy `mce`. The analogous computations in TensorFlow are further below. My question is:

**Why do I get a discrepancy between my mean cross entropy `mce` (computed with double precision in numpy) and the TensorFlow `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy`?**

I dont know, where I forgot to specify for TensorFlow to compute with double precision. Furthermore, if I use `tf.nn.reduce_mean`, see computation of `mcetf2`, on the computed cross entropy per data point, then I get my numpy result. Where does the discrepancy come from? Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#%%

# Number of data pionts nx and dimension dx
nx = 10
dx = 4

# Input data
x = np.random.rand(nx,dx)

#%% Numpy

# Transform to logits for binary classification with sigmoid
matrix = np.random.rand(dx,1)
logits = np.matmul(x,matrix)
print('Logits dimensions: %s' % str(logits.shape))

# Sigmoid
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1. / (1. + np.exp(-x))
sig = sigmoid(logits)
print('Sigmoid dimensions: %s' % str(sig.shape))

# Discrete probabilities
p = np.random.randint(2,size=nx)[:,np.newaxis]
print('Probability dimensions: %s'% str(p.shape))

# Cross entropy for each data point
ce = p*np.log(1/sig)+(1-p)*np.log(1/(1-sig))

# Mean cross entropy
mce = np.mean(ce)
print('MCE with np: %.16f' % mce)

#%% Tensorflow

xp = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64,shape=[None,dx])
pp = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64,shape=[None,1])

model = xp
c1 = tf.constant(matrix,dtype=tf.float64)
model = tf.matmul(xp,c1)
sigtf = tf.nn.sigmoid(model)
cetf = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=pp,logits=model)
mcetf = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(pp,model)
mcetf2 = tf.reduce_mean(cetf)

sess = tf.Session()
feed = {xp:x,pp:p}
print('Error in logits: %.16f' % np.max(np.abs(sess.run(model,feed)-logits)))
print('Error in sigmoid: %.16f' % np.max(np.abs(sess.run(sigtf,feed)-sig)))
print('Error in CE: %.16f' % np.max(np.abs(sess.run(cetf,feed)-ce)))
print('Error in MCE: %.16f' % np.abs(sess.run(mcetf,feed)-mce))
print('Error in MCE2: %.16f' % np.abs(sess.run(mcetf2,feed)-mce))
sess.close()
```

> Logits dimensions: (10, 1)
>
> Sigmoid dimensions: (10, 1)
>
> Probability dimensions: (10, 1)
>
> MCE with np: 0.7413128316195762
>
> Error in logits: 0.0000000000000000
>
> Error in sigmoid: 0.0000000000000000
>
> Error in CE: 0.0000000000000009
>
> Error in MCE: 0.0000000297816550
>
> Error in MCE2: 0.0000000000000001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the use of (32bit) `float`s would appear to be hard coded in the [`compute_weighted_loss()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py#L212) function used by [`sigmoid_cross_entropy`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py#L736) in Tensorflow

as a minor point your numpy code for calculating `ce` isn't very numerically stable — but it won't be affecting anything here.  I'd implement it as:

```
ce = p * -np.log(sig) + (1-p) * -np.log1p(-sig)
```

the use of [`log1p`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html) is the main change.  your use of `1 - sig` will [lose all precision](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/07/math-library-functions-that-seem-unnecessary/) as `sig` approaches zero